# Why is the Sokol suit white instead of safety orange?

Tags: spacesuits, sokol-spacesuit

The [Sokol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokol_space_suit) is a Russian rescue suit that continues to be used today$^{(1)}$ for launch and landing.  It protects the wearer from depressurization, but because it has no micrometeroid and limited thermal protection, it is not rated for EVA use.

As you can see in the picture, the Sokol is white.  This is in contrast with the equivalent American suits (LES and ACES), which are both safety orange.  Considering that Soyuz lands on land -- which may have snow cover -- one would expect safety orange to be more visible than white.

**Is there an official reason why the Sokol is white?**

[image: Sokol spacesuit]

---

$^{(1)}$ "Used today" ignoring the temporary grounding of Soyuz flights.

Related:

- [Why is the Sokol spacesuit considered inadequate for EVA?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3096/26446)
- [What are the requirements differences between Escape Suit and EVA Suit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12558/26446)
- [Do American astronauts wear Sokol space suits when flying on a Soyuz?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3095/26446)
- [Why were EVA suits never silver?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29901/26446)

Comment: It should be noted that both the old SK-1 suit used on Vostok and new modifications (not used yet) of Sokol are orange

Comment: http://www.zvezda-npp.ru/en/node/731

Comment: It does not seem required - you can't bail out of the Soyuz like you (theoretically) could out of the shuttle - so you most likely wouldn't be far from the downed capsule.

Comment: It's to make it harder for the wolves to see you if you come down in the middle of nowhere.